# How to return results with MAX value for column A by grouping on column B and where filter on Column C

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, group-by, max, where-clause

Pardon the title but this is what I have in table t1.

[image: Data Layout]

I want to return the rows for the same TRX_KEY and ID = 1 only when AMOUNT is MAX within the group. So in this case, I want following result -

[image: RESULT]

Here is the sample data -

```
create table t1( TRX_KEY int not null ,ID int null, AMOUNT int null)
insert into t1 values (1,1,1000)
insert into t1 values (1,2,100)
insert into t1 values (1,3,10)

insert into t1 values (2,1,100)
insert into t1 values (2,2,1000)
insert into t1 values (2,3,10)

insert into t1 values (3,1,5000)
insert into t1 values (3,2,1000)
insert into t1 values (3,3,10)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a window function like `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
;WITH temp AS (
    SELECT TRX_KEY, ID, Amount,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TRX_KEY ORDER BY Amount DESC) As RowNumber
    FROM    #t1
)

SELECT  *
FROM    temp
WHERE   RowNumber = 1 AND ID = 1
```

Comment: Thanks Zoff but your query gives me the record of TRX_KEY =2 which does not have the max value for ID =1. I have added sample data in my question.

Comment: So you only want rows where the max Amount belongs to `ID = 1` within each `TRX_KEY`?

Comment: Yes Sir, that's what I want. Wherever ID = 1 has max amount for the group of TRX_KEY, I want to pull that record.